# 3 Variable Optimization

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

My goal is to determine the optimal servings of turkey relative to servings rice in order to achieve a total protein/fat/carbs amount. Allow me to elaborate:

- 1 serving of turkey has 21g protein, 8g fat, and 0g carbs.
- 1 serving of rice has 4g protein, 0g fat, and 38g carbs.

My constrains are that I must have less than or equal to 336g total protein, 336g total carbs, and 75g total fat.

The primary constraint is to get as close to 336g of protien as possible, the other two can be more flexible. Here's what I thought the equation would be:

$A[4p + 0f + 38c] + B[21p + 8f + 0c] = 336p + 75f + 336c$

A = number of rice servings

B = number of turkey servings

But when I run through this (add, sub, multi, div) I never come to the right answer. So I think there is some higher level math that must be applied maybe calculus and optimizations but I can't seem to thread the needle. Any and all help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you for your help and time,

Comment: Are you restricted to integers?  In this particular example, have as much as possible of turkey without breaking the fat constraint and as much as possible of rice without breaking the carbs constraint.  Other examples may require a more sophisticated approach

Comment: No we can use fractions. Doesn't need to be a whole servings @Henry

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a single equality constraint, you should have a separate constraint for each nutrient.  Usually in the *diet problem*, the objective is to minimize cost subject to lower bounds on nutrients.  For your variant, introduce a nonnegative slack variable $s$.  The problem is to minimize $s$ subject to:
\begin{align}
4 A + 21 B + s &= 336 \\
0 A + 8 B &\le 75\\
38 A + 0 B &\le 336
\end{align}

Comment: So I would just solve this like a standard 3 variable system of equations? @RobPratt

Comment: If you have not studied linear programming, the expected approach is probably to solve this graphically.  That is, graph the line corresponding to the equation $4A+21B=336$ and the shaded regions corresponding to the two inequalities and see which point $(A,B)$ in the shaded region is closest to the line without going above it.

Comment: That's helpful thank you I'll give that a go. I haven't studied linear programming but If you could point me to the concept(s) that would allow me to solve this I could probably figure it out with some time. Would you mind? I'd like to learn the right way to do this if possible @RobPratt